# xcodebuild destination with id logs warning with duplicates

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I run xcode tests on a simulated device with this script line:

```
xcodebuild test \
    -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace \
    -scheme My-Scheme \
    -destination 'id=12345678-ASDF-ASDF-ASDF-64DB01A47924'
```

But it then logs a warning:

```
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:12345678-ASDF-ASDF-ASDF-64DB01A47924, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:12345678-ASDF-ASDF-ASDF-64DB01A47924, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
```

This doesn't make sense to me, how can there be any ambiguity or a duplication when using the unique identifier?

To debug, I opened the "Devices and Simulators" menu in Xcode and found my simulator device there. It showed only once.

I then opened `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/` and found that the id appeared once as a directory there.

Then I ran: `xcrun simctl list | grep 12345678-ASDF-ASDF-ASDF-64DB01A47924` and again, only one output.

Am I doing something wrong with my xcodebuild invocation or is this a bug?

```
xcodebuild -version
Xcode 15.1
Build version 15C65
```